# How to change font size with shell script?

Tags: shell, unix

Is there any way to change the size of the text in shell script ?
I mean dynamically during the execution .

For example I have an image drawn with ASCII code and i want to reduce the size of text .
Now when echo or cat the image it will be shown as the command prompt actual size (the actual font size) .

Comment: The size and font used to display the text in a terminal is under the control of the terminal emulator, so I don't think there will be any way to do what you want.

Comment: There is an escape sequence to change the font of an xterm, and `xtermset` provides a simple scriptable interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of comments note that font size/style are under the control of the terminal emulator, and that xterm (and a few others) support escape sequences to change these.

However - almost all terminal emulators (all that you would be likely to encounter) rely upon keeping the characters in a nice row/column grid.  All of the characters have the "same" size.  If you change the size of the font in xterm, all of the characters on the screen change to the same size.  So there is no way to (as OP asks) to reduce the font-size temporarily, e.g., while using ASCII graphics to draw a picture using [aalib](http://aa-project.sourceforge.net/aalib/), etc.

If you want to do something like that, the easiest way to do it is to have the script run its graphics in a separate window, e.g., by splitting it up into one part that starts the window and another script to draw the graphics.

For an alternate via of terminals and fonts, there is always something like [9term](https://swtch.com/plan9port/man/man1/9term.html) (*no* rows, *no* columns, *no* vi).